# Unity default ThirdPersonController error

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a player spawning in the scene upon it's start. Using the standard assets, I've dragged the default ThirdPersonController.

However, when I run, although the player spawns correctly, [this error](https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/5712977712f791da014c6c7a/960x441/48cd4898b5f8d983bfb2fb8484eb6886/error.png) comes along.

[This is the default script](https://itextpad.com/oicOh3I5dT) from the standard assets (which I've made no change to).

The way I'm saving and loading the character is with two scripts: [GameMaster][3] and [GameSettings][4] (which are generated along with the player).

Please notice that the default camera that should follow the player is also not working. What am I missing?

Best,
Sporting

Comment: [3]: https://itextpad.com/EOSvuNTMFn
  [4]: https://itextpad.com/Uiy4oqKh90

Last two links here, sorry.

Comment: I assume you didnt change anything in ThridPersonController? Did you maybe remove the animator? the only variable in CheckGroundStatus() which actually can be null is m_Animator, the rest (Vector3 and bool) are value types and would have their default value (Vector3.zero or false)

Comment: it usually means something you trying to access is null! simply go at that line and log it and check why it is null

Comment: Still cannot fix. Anyone can help me please?